# Процедурная генерация дома или чего-либо в Unity

Tags: unity3d, procedural-generation

Я создал генератор домов и кастомный редактор для инспектора, но остались вопросы:

1. я строю дом из блоков которые переедаю в инспекторе, и делаю их копии через Instantiate, в результате у меня выходит куса экземпляров этого объекта в окне иерархии. Это нормально, на сказывается на производительности?
2. Мне нужно динамически менять дом под вводимые в инструктор параметры, как мне отловить что какое-то поле изменилось?
3. При этом, визимо, необходимо уничтожить все потомки, я нашёл функцию которая перебирает их всех и вызывает destroy(). Но она как-то не всегда правильно работает. Имеет смысл не удалять объекты, а сохранять ссылки на них и убирать в некоторый пул неиспользованнных элементов?

Comment: чего гадать, код кидай

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ровно на столько же сказывается на производительности как и созданные обьекты без инициализации програмным кодом, а созданием через эдитор. Тут еще много зависит от того какие компоненты ты на каждый обьект вешаешь. Если у тебя очень много элементов с RigitBody - имей ввиду что будет лагать) Загугли тесты производительности с разным количеством коробок или бочек в юнити.
2. при смене любой переменной в инспекторе вызывается OnValidate. Это ты и можешь использовать для себя.
3. сделай метод который убивает всех детей обьекта, а потом вызывает дестрой у самого себя.

```
     public void DestroyMeAndChildren()
     {
         foreach (Transform child in gameObject.transform) {
             GameObject.Destroy(child.gameObject);
         }
         gameObject.Destroy;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. А куса это сколько? А сколько полигонов, материалов, разрешение?
2. В custom editor это делается очень просто, присваивая значение из GUILayout, другой переменной и сравнивая эту переменную и поле target класса.
3. Уничтожить чьих потомков? В редакторе нужно использовать `DestroyImmediate`.